# How to match a hidden folder in next 13 middleware matcher

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, frontend, middleware

I have this segment path: "/(protected)/" in my next13 app where I want to place all my protected pages.

To achieve that, I need a way to match that path segment in the middleware matcher as follows:

```
export const config = {
  matcher: '/(protected)/:path*',
}
```

Is that a way of doing that?

I have tried the following:

```
export const config = {
  matcher: '/(protected)/:path*',
}

export const config = {
  matcher: '/protected/:path*',
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to match route groups since they are not reflected in the actual page path.